# Faraday's electromagnetic induction

Tags: electromagnetism, induction

Does the emf increase when no of turns of the same wire increased?

Consider a wire of length 'l' is coiled with an area of cross section 'A' is subjected to a change in magnetic flux. an emf will be induced ?

If i use the same wire of length 'l' which is coiled to an area of cross section 'a' is subjected to the same change in flux. Will the emf increase ?

where A > a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Faraday’s Second Law,
 the magnitude of emf induced in the coil is equal to the rate of change of flux that linkages with the coil.

if the flux change in both coils are same then emf created will be same.(but current can be different).

http://electrical4u.com/faraday-law-of-electromagnetic-induction/

Comment: Wont the increased no of turns matter ?

Comment: If the magnetic flux through the coil same even if the no of coil changes then emf should be same.(as you have assumed)
but  generally changing the no of coils changes the rate of change of flux.

Comment: So if the same length is used no change in emf. right ? here 'no of coil changes the rate of flux' means the case when additional piece of wire is made into a coil.

Comment: @Vinayak: Flux through a coil depends on its geometry.(lenght ,area etc etc.).Flux determines the number of field lines passing through the coil.so if you change geometry(lenght ,area etc etc) so flux through the coil may change.
in that case rate of change of magnetic flux can also be different for different coils..
Then emf will be different..but in your question you have assumed rate of change of magnetic flux is same so emf should be same.
http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_induction

Comment: now its clear..thank u...could u please help me with this question ? http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/167593/resistance-in-potentiometer?noredirect=1#comment354137_167593